# Proj4 Convert any CRS to ECEF

Tags: proj

How can I convert a point in a given CRS I know, to ECEF, using Proj4?

Is there an EPSG code for ECEF coordinates? Or is there a way to create a proj4 transform object to convert from and to ECEF coordinates?

Comment: Possibly try the +geoc option. I don't know if it will accept EPSG:4978.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the C API:
Create your Proj4 objects with pj_init_plus(), which takes a proj4 string as an argument. You must know the proj4 strings that correspond to your origin and destiny CRS. Then use pj_transform to transform the points from one CRS to the other.

Alternatively you can use the cs2cs tool, which also takes the proj4 strings as arguments. Link: http://proj4.org/apps/cs2cs.html